# How can I call different ModelForm for different objects using object class name?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

How can I call different ModelForm for different objects using object class name?

## models.py

```
class First(models.Model):

class Second(models.Model):
```

## forms.py

```
class FirstForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = First

class SecondForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Second
```

## views.py

```
def call_form(request, my_object_id):
    my_object = my_object.__class__.__name__.objects.get(pk = my_object_id)

    #    it should looks like below
    #    form = FirstForm(instance = my_object)
    #    or
    #    form = SecondForm(instance = my_object)
    #
    #    form = my_object.__class__.__name__ .... end what then?

    return render(request, 'template_name.html', {'form': form})
```

Could anyone help me a bit with this?
Thanks a lot with advance.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing is just to create a dictionary mapping models to classes:

```
form_dict = {
    First: FirstForm,
    Second: SecondForm,
}

def call_form(request, my_object_id):
    ...
    form_class = form_dict[my_object.__class__]
```

(Note I'm not sure how you're passing the object into the view to get the class; seems like that should be a parameter, but it isn't.)

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I don't know what to add after form=my_object.__class__.__name__ [some_code_here] to call full name of proper ModelForm. Could I ask you a hint?

Comment: What? Did you read my answer? The code there tells you what to do.

Comment: Don't get mad on me, please. It's just not clear for me. You mean to add form_class to my_object.__class__.__name__?

Comment: No, I'm not mad but I really don't understand what you mean. My code gives you the form class itself, I don't know why you want to do anything with the class name. You can just instantiate it: `form = form_class(request.POST)` or whatever.